# Check email matches specified domain(s) or reject

Tags: php, javascript, email, whitelist

Currently my email accepts all email domains. I would like to define which ones are allowed out of a list (solent.ac.uk, herts.ac.uk) rather than public ones such as @gmail.com etc. Whichever way is easiest for now, i'll try alternative ways for now, this is more just temporary.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php url_for('register'); ?>">

  <!--Email-->
  <p class="email field">
    <input tabindex="1" id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" placeholder="email@example.com" autofocus />
    <a href="<?php url_for('login'); ?>" tabindex="2" class="action button register" title="Click to log-in with your existing account.">Login</a>
  </p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version in PHP

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $whitelist = array('solent.ac.uk', 'herts.ac.uk');
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    list(, $domain) = array_pad(explode('@', $email, 2), 2, '');
    if (in_array($domain, $whitelist)) {
      // you're good
    }
    else {
      // not so good
    }

    // more data validation
}
```

Comment: I'd go with `list(, $domain) = array_pad(explode('@', $email, 2), 2, '');` as `list` is rather unforgiving when the array does not fit in size.

Comment: I understand what that code is doing but where I put it im unsure. I'm a beginner with PHP.

Comment: Wherever the form submission goes is where you put this. At the top of the page with all of your other data validation.

Comment: I've got things added, wondered if it were possible to define just an extension instead of each universities email extension (obviously yes this is based on university student emails only).

So I could just allow all .ac.uk ending emails instead of having to list all solent.ac.uk, herts.ac.uk, etc..

Comment: That would work just as well. In fact it would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I changed it to just '.ac.uk' but it just rejects the email like it's incorrect. Is that the correct way '.ac.uk', does it matter if it starts with a period?

Comment: The period won't matter. What you will need to do is change the part where you get the domain name name. You don't want the whole name anymore. Now you just need the TLD.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<form>` you could break the email into two pieces; the username and the domain. The username would be a typical text input and the domain portion would be a select drop down box.

A simplified example is below:

```
<input type="text" name="email_username" />@
<select name="email_domain">
  <option value="domain1.com">@domain1.com</option>
  <option value="domain2.com">@domain2.com</option>
  <option value="domain3.com">@domain3.com</option>
  <option value="domain4.com">@domain4.com</option>
</select>
```